# Add (insert) new row textbox in grid view programmatically not showing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

so I have this code for grid view in asp.net

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdNewClaim" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed" GridLines="None" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="claim_type" HeaderText="Claim Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="purpose_desc" HeaderText="Purpos/Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="currency" HeaderText="Currency" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency Rate">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChangeCurrRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Converted Rate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChangeConvertedRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And this code to add the new row for the gridview

```
    Private Sub addClaimProgrammatically()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        If grdNewClaim.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            dt.Columns.Add("claim_type")
            dt.Columns.Add("purpose_desc")
            dt.Columns.Add("currency")
            dt.Columns.Add("amount")
            dt.Columns.Add("txtChangeCurrRate")
            dt.Columns.Add("txtChangeConvertedRate")


            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr.Item("claim_type") = cmbClaimtype.Text
            dr.Item("purpose_desc") = txtPurpDesc.Text
            dr.Item("currency") = cmbCurrency.Value
            dr.Item("amount") = txtAmmount.Text
            dr.Item("txtChangeCurrRate") = lblCurrencyrate.Text
            dr.Item("txtChangeConvertedRate") = lblconvertedRateMYR.Text
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If
      

        grdNewClaim.DataSource = dt
        grdNewClaim.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

But for some reason the items for for both textbox just blank like this : [image: like this]

So any idea why? Because if I change the textbox to `<asp:BoundField/>`  it works just fine like this
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**EDIT : create another rows in gridview**

My markup is exactly the same as you. So this is my code behind. This code works just fine, however the only problem is my textbox for first row went blank. The second row is alright.

NOTE : I didn't do this on page_load.

```
    Private Sub LoadGrid()
        grdNewClaim.DataSource = dtGrd
        grdNewClaim.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub addClaimProgrammatically()
        Dim dr As DataRow
        If grdNewClaim.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("claim_type")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("purpose_desc")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("currency")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("amount")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("CurrencyRate")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("ConvertedRate")

            dr = dtGrd.NewRow
            dr.Item("claim_type") = cmbClaimtype.Text
            dr.Item("purpose_desc") = txtPurpDesc.Text
            dr.Item("currency") = cmbCurrency.Value
            dr.Item("amount") = txtAmmount.Text
            dr.Item("CurrencyRate") = lblCurrencyrate.Text
            dr.Item("ConvertedRate") = lblconvertedRateMYR.Text
            dtGrd.Rows.Add(dr)

        ElseIf grdNewClaim.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("claim_type")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("purpose_desc")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("currency")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("amount")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("CurrencyRate")
            dtGrd.Columns.Add("ConvertedRate")

            For i = 0 To grdNewClaim.Rows.Count - 1
                dr = dtGrd.NewRow
                dr.Item("claim_type") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
                dr.Item("purpose_desc") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text
                dr.Item("currency") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text
                dr.Item("amount") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text
                dr.Item("CurrencyRate") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text
                dr.Item("ConvertedRate") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(6).Text
                dtGrd.Rows.Add(dr)
            Next
            dr = dtGrd.NewRow
            dr.Item("claim_type") = cmbClaimtype.Text
            dr.Item("purpose_desc") = txtPurpDesc.Text
            dr.Item("currency") = cmbCurrency.Value
            dr.Item("amount") = txtAmmount.Text
            dr.Item("CurrencyRate") = lblCurrencyrate.Text
            dr.Item("ConvertedRate") = lblconvertedRateMYR.Text
            dtGrd.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If
        LoadGrid()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnAddClaim_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddClaim.Click
     addClaimProgrammatically()
    End Sub
```

The values just went missing
[image]

Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a boundfield, it works because you CAN SPECIFY which column to display.

bound field only works due to this:

[image]

Computers do not "guess" or "assume" what data column to use here.

But, when you use a templated column, and a standard control, then you need to use a expression that defines which column to use.

eg this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency Rate">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtChangeCurrRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

so, in above, ask this question:
Where in above does the markup KNOW which column to use?

So, you have to use a binding expression, since TextBox does not have a "boundfield" property to tell it which column to use.

Try like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency Rate">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtChangeCurrRate" runat="server"
      Text = '<%# Eval("Currency") %>'
      ></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So, in above, we would be using column "Currency" for the text (or  you can use "amount" or "purpose_desc" or any column from the data source.

So, your example does not work, since with a templated textbox, you have to specify the column to use - (by some how and some way). So, use the above binding expression.

## Edit: data does not persist - only can add one row.

Correct - you need to save that table between each post-back, and NOT re-create the table from scratch each time, else you lose previous rows.

So, the code has to look like this:

NOTE how I defined dt at the class level (right before page load).

And note how I "restore" this dt in page load EACH time.

So, your code will become this

Markup like this:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grdNewClaim" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed" 
            GridLines="None" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="claim_type" HeaderText="Claim Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="purpose_desc" HeaderText="Purpos/Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="currency" HeaderText="Currency" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency Rate">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCRateZoo" runat="server"
                    Text = '<%# Eval("txtChangeCurrRate") %>'>
                </asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Converted Rate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConvertedRate" runat="server"                        
                    Text = '<%# Eval("txtChangeCurrRate") %>' >

                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And code now like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        CreateTable()
        LoadGrid()
        Session("dt") = dt

    Else
        ' restore table
        dt = Session("dt")
    End If

End Sub


Sub CreateTable()

    dt.Columns.Add("claim_type", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("purpose_desc")
    dt.Columns.Add("currency", GetType(Double))
    dt.Columns.Add("amount", GetType(Double))
    dt.Columns.Add("txtChangeCurrRate", GetType(Double))
    dt.Columns.Add("txtChangeConvertedRate", GetType(Double))

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    grdNewClaim.DataSource = dt
    grdNewClaim.DataBind()

End Sub


Private Sub addClaimProgrammatically()

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr.Item("claim_type") = cmbClaimtype.Text
    dr.Item("purpose_desc") = txtPurpDesc.Text
    dr.Item("currency") = cmbCurrency.Value
    dr.Item("amount") = txtAmmount.Text
    dr.Item("txtChangeCurrRate") = lblCurrencyrate.Text
    dr.Item("txtChangeConvertedRate") = lblconvertedRateMYR.Text
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    LoadGrid()

End Sub
```

## Edit2: allow edits of two text box - save back to table.

So, just add this to the code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        CreateTable()
        LoadGrid()
        Session("dt") = dt

    Else
        ' restore table
        dt = Session("dt")
        ' restore grid to dt
        GridToTable
    End If

End Sub

Sub GridToTable()

    ' move any and all possile updates to grid back to our table dt

    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In grdNewClaim.Rows

        Dim OneRow As DataRow = dt.Rows(gRow.RowIndex)
        Dim txtCurrRate As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtCRateZoo")
        Dim txtConvertRate As TextBox = gRow.FindControl("txtConvertedRate")

        OneRow("txtChangeCurrRate") = txtCurrRate.Text
        OneRow("txtChangeConvertedRate") = txtConvertRate.Text

    Next

End Sub
```

What we do is send any changes back to the dt.

This means, that any button click etc on that page will shuffle gv back to dt.

This also means that if you have a button click to jump or move on to the next page/url, then session("dt") will have the correct data.

but, since we doing this on page load, then don't use a link button, or a button with post-back url to jump to the next page (just use regular button + code behind, and say:

```
 Response.Redirect("url to next page to jump to")
```

So, with above, user can now freely modify the two columns, and they will be sent back to the dt.

This also means you can loop/process the dt in code.

Say we drop a button on the form, and then behind that button we do this:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Each OneRow As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Debug.Print(OneRow("currency"))
        Debug.Print(OneRow("txtChangeCurrRate"))
        ' etc . etc.
    Next

End Sub
```

So, we don't even have to hit the original grid, and our dt will be always updated in our session(). So, we now can work with table in code - not have to use the grid. As such, then we could have a button "continue" to move on to the next page - as along as we follow above setup, then dt will always have the latest data and edits upon a post-back.

Comment: I understand it now. thank you. It works btw. However when I added another row, first row items in the textbox went blank. Then I try debug, there were no values for the textbox in `dr.Item("CurrencyRate") = grdNewClaim.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text`. `dr` is DataRow

Comment: Well, in your posted code, you create a WHOLE new table from scratch, add one row, send to grid, and then you are done. When you run that code again, you create a WHOLE new table from scratch, add one row, and send to grid. So, remember, your values don't persist in code - they go out of scope when the page is done rendering. This means you need to shove and save the data table into Session() or viewstate. I'll  post some code as to how this can (has) to work - wait about 5 min.

Comment: Check the markup - I had some errors - I was WRONG useing =, you have to use %# not %=. Also, if you want to allow user to modify the values - then we need a bit more code - ask if you need this ability. Because we re-bind from the table, then if user is to type in those rates, or change them in the grid, then we need to send values back to our persisted table. If not required, then no worry, but if user is to type new values into GV, then if we add row, the edits will be lost - but it a simple matter to send edits back to the dt. (and without templates or a bunch of special code).

Comment: Yes. I have checked it and corrected it. and yes, I want to allow the user to modify the values. can you help me with it ?

Comment: see edit#2  - it rather easy to do this (and most examples suggest all kinds of templates etc. - you don't need as such. You are now free to tab around like excel - edit any values. Any button click (post-back) will cause update of values to dt. This includes the existing code to add a new row.

Comment: I see. Thanks. But I do a bit different than you. Because whenever I do on page_load it'll give me an error saying the rows already exist in datatable. give me a minute I'll edit my question so you can see.

Comment: You have to seperate out the create table code, and the add a new row code as I have done. Since the table will ALWAYS exist after first page load, then such code that attempts to re-create the columns does not make sense. You left out the MOST imporant bit of code - that is your page load event. You MUST use the  if Not IsPostback Event - in fact the last 150+ pages I have written even without this code without question near ALWAYS but ALWAYS needs to run your data load, and setup code ONE time inside of that Not IsPostBack stub. The code I posted works fine - including edits.

Comment: Remember, ANY button click on a page will always trigger page load event BEFORE your button code stub runs - this is the case for all such pages. You can't quite much build a working page if you don't follow this rule and use that Not IsPostBack to run such code ONLY on the real first page load. After that occurs, then all other post backs will run the code to restore the dt.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. This thing is very new to me. again Thank you !

Comment: It work now ! My only mistake is because I put the `createTable()` in btnAddClaim handler. How could I be so careless for a simple mistake. Thank you very much for your time. I appreciated so much !

Comment: ouh yes, it also because my code on page_load was not in a good structure since there are others code on page_load. so perhaps it was confuse with my codes.